# PHP Script Parsing Files Incorrectly

Tags: php

I am not exactly sure what the problem is, but I have a PHP script which should be downloading and displaying specified web pages. However, certain pages create a download dialog in the browser rather than displaying the page (but the downloaded file is still the correct HTML). This only happens for some websites but I am not sure what makes the difference.

I have messed around with the content type headers and I do not think this is the problem, but could this be a client-side problem somehow? I do not know where to look to figure out how to debug this, so I would appreciate any help that points me in the right direction.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: How are you displaying the webpages?

Answer (score 3):

Install firebug, and examine response headers to figure out what's being sent, probably `Content-Type` or `Content-Disposition` header.

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed that Firefox presents a download dialog if it encounters a NULL byte in the source (binary data).